# How to deal with concrete security against lots of queries?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, probability

In general, $O(1/\epsilon^2)$ queries are required to distinguish between two distributions that are statistically close at most $\epsilon$.

This informal state deals with the required number of queries to distinguish between two distributions. However, I cannot find any statement that when we have $Q$ queries, then we can distinguish two distributions under some $P$ probability.

I have a few questions about some common knowledge in cryptographic fields.

1. How can I formally write the statement about concrete security against lots of queries?
2. How we set parameter to be secure against adversaries allowed $Q$ queries? As standard decision problems, adversary has a negligible advantage?
3. Why NIST PQC standardization recommend parameters to be secure against number of queries $2^{64}$? Is there a special reason? What is implicit consensus relate to $2^{64}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinguishing distributions is studied in the field of distribution testing. See [this survey](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/toc/articles/gs009/gs009.pdf) for more information.
In particular, I believe the survey states that the correct sample bound includes a term roughly of the form $O(|\Omega|/\epsilon^2)$, where $\Omega$ is the support of the underlying distribution.

As for your particular questions:

1. Generally, query-bounds arise within cryptography when making Renyi-divergence arguments, as one can often make significant gains by bounding the queries (say as $q \leq 2^{64}$, rather than $2^{128}$, which is the "trivial" bound for 128-bit security). See for example [this slides](https://tprest.github.io/pdf/slides/renyi-discrete-subgroup.pdf) of Thomas Prest's (or in general his recent publications --- he has been quite interested in developing renyi divergence arguments in lattice cryptography).
2. For setting parameters when you're allowed to institute query bounds, see the slides. In particular, he works through the example of a particular algorithm (the Micciancio Walter convolution sampler) that claimed 100 bits of security, and shows that (up to $2^{96}$ queries) the sampler actually achieves 256 bits of security. For a different algorithm, he is able to set parameters such that certain state required for the algorithm is an order of magnitude smaller.

I can't really speak to the third question in any concrete way though.

Comment: Thank you. But I still confuse at some points. Thomas Prest's slides only deals with a search problem, but distinguishing two distributions are one of decision problems. How to convert a decision problem into a search problem? I think it is quite important since he already said Renyi divergence argument is not tight at decision problem. Also, what happen if a support $\Omega$ is unbounded like Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Generally one does not use distributions of unbounded support within cryptography, as it is relatively simple to show they are impossible to sample from in constant time (note that you can sample from such distributions in expected constant time using Knuth Yao sampling). Instead you usually take some "approximation" to the distribution (for Gaussians this is known as "tail cutting"). Section 4 of [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.738.1913&rep=rep1&type=pdf) discusses some of the issues with using RD arguments for decision problems.

Comment: As for "Thomas Prest's slides only deals with a search problem, but distinguishing two distributions are one of decision problems.", there is some subtlety here that may be worth asking another question. I believe the "search" or "decision" statement refers to the *underlying cryptographic hardness assumption* (in lattices, one can use search-LWE). See for example page 10 of [this Prest paper](https://tprest.github.io/pdf/pub/renyi.pdf). That being said, this is discussed more informally than I would prefer in the paper, and I have not worked through these arguments myself formally.

Comment: Thanks again for your kind reply. Good!